# A silly doubt on the concept of volume percent and concentration

Tags: concentration

I am trying to solve the following elementary problem of volume percent, however, I am not quite sure where my mistake is:

*Ethanol has a volume-by-volume concentration of 93.3%. Calculate the volume of water in $\pu{10 L}$ of this alcohol.*

My Attempts:

By definition,

$$\text{volume concentration} = \frac{\text{volume of solute}}{\text{volume of solution}} \times 100\%$$

From the exercise, we know that $\text{volume concentration} =93.3\%$ and $\text{volume of solute} = \pu{10 L}$. By substituting those values in the equation above, we then have

$$93.3\%=\frac{\pu{10 L}} {\text{volume of solution}} \times 100\%$$

Working forward from the last equation and solving it for the volume of the solution, we find

$\text{volume of solution} = \pu{10.71 L}$. Therefore, the volume of water or the volume of solvent becomes

$$\text{volume of solution} = \text{volume of solute} + \text{volume of solvent}$$

$$ \pu{10.71 L} = \pu{10 L} + \text{volume of solvent}$$

Therefore, $\text{volume of solvent} = \pu{0.71 L}$.

However, the actual answer to this problem is $\pu{667 g}$.
Based on the above, what is my mistake here?

Comment: For future reference: for the body of questions, answers and comments, chemistry.se allows to use [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/).  In addition to assistance typing chemical formulae, the `\pu{}` command allows to type values with units including a non-breakable space (and units typically are upright, too).

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Answer (score 5):

First of all it is a stupid problem.

- Volumes don't add. So 90.00 ml of ethanol and 10.00 ml of water doesn't yield 100.00 ml of solution.
- The problem messes up significant figures. 10 L and 93.3% ethanol in the problem statement suddenly become 10.000 liters and 93.33% in the problem solution.
- The problem statement is given in terms of volumes, but the answer for water is given in grams.

So the problem assumes that volumes do add and that the *final solution (a mixture of ethanol and water)* has a volume of 10.000 liters. Since the solution is 93.3% ethanol, 6.7% is water. So about 670 ml of water. Now further assuming that water is 1 gram per ml (since no temperature is given) that means that there is about 670 grams of water.

---

Your mistake - In your second equation the 10 L should be in the denominator not the numerator.

Comment: Well, does "10 L of the alcohol" mean 10 L of the impure liquid, or the volume of liquid that contains 10 L of pure alcohol after separation? I agree with "stupid problem".

Comment: @Karsten - LOL In order to get the "right" answer it must be 10 L of the ethanol/water mixture. // Getting crotchety in my old age. I think problems out to adhere to the real science. The problems are supposed to be teaching chemistry too.

Comment: Yes, they ought to.